# How to view boot up log (scripts/daemons)

Tags: boot

I'm seeing an error concerning some daemon script at boot-up. Unfortunately it flies by too fast for me to catch what it says.

From searching the web, I have understood that [bootlogd](https://wiki.debian.org/bootlogd) could previously be used to write a file to `/var/log`, but it doesn't seem to work since the Debian update to Jessie.

Are there any ways for me to get a clear log of the boot-up screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken (have no raspbian right now) Jessie runs `systemd` for logging. The journal could be querried using the utility `journalctl`. See `man journalctl` for usage.

It is advisable to obtain root privileges or use `sudo` to get full access to system logs. As per `man journalctl`:

> All users are granted access to their private per-user journals. However, by default, only root and users who are members of a few special groups are granted access to the system journal and the journals of other users. Members of the groups "systemd-journal", "adm", and "wheel" can read all journal files. Note that the two latter groups traditionally have additional privileges specified by the distribution.

Comment: Jessie does run systemd, and you need `sudo` to see system logs

Comment: While any user could issue `journalctl` and will get some results, access to the system journal is granted only root and a few special groups. So right.

Comment: @Milliways Do know the exact command to view the logs in the OP?

Comment: For starters, how about `sudo journalctl`?